# How to load app specific template tag in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm calling this template tag from a different app within the same project. However I'd like to make changes on it to make it work better on the app I'm working on.

I simply created a `templatetags` directory inside my app and copied the template tag file inside then went about my changes. So it kinda looks like this:

```
theotherapp/templatetags/sometags.py
myapp/templatetags/sometags.py
```

What I noticed is that the other app's template tag is still the one being used. But when I change the filename of the template tag in my app ...

```
myapp/templatetags/sometags.py -> myapp/templatetags/sometags_myapp.py
```

and then rename the template tags loaded to the new one in my script, it works as intended. But I don't want to do it that way.

**My question is:**
How do I let Django know to use the template tag script local to my app given that it has the same filename with another app's template tag?

But I'd still like to retain that Django still looks into the other app's template tags as the other apps in the projects are depending on it.

I'm using Django 1.3 by the way.

Comment: Check how you load the tag, an unupdated load tag like: `{% load sometags_myapp %}` is probably the culprit here.

Comment: I don't think I have a problem with that. What I'm wondering about is whether if Django can be set to prioritize loading the template tags local to the app, provided that another app (within the same project) has the same template tag filename.

Comment: Have you checked? From the docs `The name of the module file is the name you’ll use to load the tags later, so be careful to pick a name that won’t clash with custom tags and filters in another app`

Comment: Oh I didn't know this one. So that means that I have to come up with unique filenames for my template tags. I also tried doing the "dot notation"/"from" call but Django says my package is invalid.

Comment: I guess I was just expecting the behavior that Django would prioritize reading from the more "local" file. Oh well, guess I'll just be sticking with just renaming the template tag file differently. Thanks for taking the time checking this out.

Comment: No worries, it really didnt take much effort! Hope it helps! :D