# 2 third party apps with the same name for their template tag files. How to load them?

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetags

```
app1
 - templatetags
   - __init__.py
   - tags.py

app2
 - templatetags
   - __init__.py
   - tags.py
```

If you do `{% load tags %}` in a template then one of these is used (the one that is defined first in settings.py installed apps). How can you load app specific template tags?

Is there any way that you can change the name of the tags of one app without affecting the actual file name? (they are 3rd party django apps)

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30229600/2369865) similar question but in that case the module names are not the same, so it's a different situation.

There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16050990/2369865) question which asks the same thing, but it has no answer.

I tried using the `from` directive without success
`{% load tags from app2 %}` TemplateSyntaxError: 'app2' is not a valid tag library..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this, in which there are 2 apps with the same file name for their template tags, then only the template tags of the **first** encountered app (*as they are defined in the installed_apps in settings*) is accessible when `{% load tags %}`.

So, I finally used this workaround.

```
my_app
 - templatetags
   - __init__
   - app2_tags_copy.py
```

I created a new tags file (the **app2_tags_copy.py**) in one of my apps and I imported the template tag code of the second app. All that this file has, is one line of import code:

```
from app2.templatetags.tags import *
```

This way you can use the tags.py code using the app2_tags_copy.py name by just doing `{% load app2_tags_copy %}` in the templates. Even if app2 is updated, the updated tags code will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `from` directive:

```
{% load tags from app1 %}
{% load tags from app2 %}
```

Comment: Yes I did, but it doesn't work (i included it in the question). I get a TemplateSybtaxError 'app2' is not a valid tag librabry.